# From frontend to DDD to API calls, how to navigate in the wild west?

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design

I am so confused!
I'm learning DDD and it's really tough to wrap my head around it, especially as a Frontend dev.
so my question for you today is where should i put api calls?
as dar as i understand any request to external sources should be in the infrastructure layer. however, i'm not sure under which tactical part, Entity or service or even a repository?
still trying to grasp all the info, so apologies in advance if the question is a bit off

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a Gateway.

The usecase would at some point call something like `userGateway.findUser(userId)`

The `userGateway` would be an instance of the `UserGateway` interface.

Now you can implement either a `HttpUserGateway` or `GraphqlGateway` in your infrastructure layer. Even swap between the two in the middle of the project for any reason.